# mysql date and time auto stamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to separately insert a Date into one field m_DATE (11-10-2010) and then a time into m_TIME (01:15:03) either 24hr or 12hr with an am/pm. How would I go about doing this.

Sorry I don't have any example to work with I know there is Current_Timestamp but that does everything in one field.

Comment: You can split it into two different variables in PHP... it doesn't have to be stored in the DB that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

for the date part and

```
select TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

for the time part. If you want the date and the time of another timestamp than CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, you pass your own parameter to the above mentioned function.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_TIME` would return the same without needing to use TIME/DATE in your examples.  But CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is ANSI...